# Exporting LaTeX from Lyx

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX 2.3.4.2 (2020-02-07) to produce LaTeX sources under Ubuntu 20.04.
Formerly, I could export my .lyx file to .tex. Recently I added a new figure, the first one. First I attempted to add the figure in .pdf form, but LyX replied with the error message "error converting to loadable format". I also attempted to convert the file to .eps, but the error message persists. Despite the error message, the image is present in the preview file. Given that the visual appearance with the .pdf file is better, I  removed the reference to the .eps file. Now when I want to export my .lyx file to a .tex file, the open dialog says that it wants to overwite my (already unrelated) .eps file, and I can either cancel the operation or overwrite that file. When I remove the .eps file, then the export works OK. Is this issue known?
Is it possible to insert a \figure? (not simply include a graphic file).

Comment: When exporting from LyX to LaTeX, LaTeX also includes the dependencies, I think. Apparently the flavor you're exporting to does not support .pdf figures, so LyX converts the .pdf to .eps. That's why you get prompted about overwriting.

Comment: Well, the funny is that both .eps and .pdf figures are shown in the preview; so they are 'half-supported'. The other thing is that I want to export the TeX text to a .tex file, rather than to some unrelated .eps file (the names of the .lyx and .eps files are different).

Comment: We might be misunderstanding each other (sorry, I'm trying!), but what I wanted to point out is that when you export to .tex LyX also saves the .eps files as a secondary effect. If you choose "overwrite", than look in the current working directory and you'll find the .tex file that you want. I think you were expecting a separate dialog of where to save the .tex file but that's not how "File > Export" works. It is, however, how "File > Export *as*" works.